# Django pass variable with form submission

Tags: django

I've got a form that users submit. They will fill in the first 3 fields and then I want to put a variable to be recorded at the same time.

For example: 
They will fill in Name, DOB, Address and then press submit. However I also want to capture IP address each time the form is submitted. I'm using ipware to get the IP address into a variable in the views.py. But how can I included this IP variable to be submitted with the other fields.

Views.py

```
def server_update(request, pk, template_name='servers/server_form.html'):
    server = get_object_or_404(Server, pk=pk)
    form = ServerForm(request.POST or None, instance=server)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('server_list')
    return render(request, template_name, {'form':form})
```

server_form.html

```
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
<!--      {{ form.as_p }}  this brings in the whole form -->

    Name <br>
    {{ form.name }} <br>
    Order <br>
    {{ form.order }} <br>
    First name <br>
    {{ form.first_name }} <br><br>


    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
```

models.py

```
class Server(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    order = models.IntegerField()
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    ip = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)    

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('server_edit', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: send the ip address along with form when form is rendered and make a hidden field inside form to store IP. then with form submit get it

Comment: Thanks @AjayGupta that seems like the best idea. I'm not that familar with forms yet.  I've got my form field{{ form.ip }}  and my IP variable{{ ip }} how can I put these together and make the form field hidden. Thanks :)

Comment: This is how my form is setup at the moment class ServerForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model =  Server
        fields = ['name', 'order', 'first_name', 'ip']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set it on save.

```
if form.is_valid():
    obj = form.save(commit=False)
    obj.ip = get_ip_from_wherever()
    obj.save()
    return redirect('server_list')
```

Answer (score 0):

make your form like this

```
ServerForm(ModelForm): 
       class Meta:
             model = Server 
             fields = ['name', 'order', 'first_name']
```

now when this form gets rendered add another field ip in html.

```
<form>
{{yourform}}
<input type='hidden' name='ip' value={{your ip from view}}
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks @Ajay I tried this one it worked fine getting the variable into the field however I believe I might have to do something else in the view after post because it didn't save the IP. Maybe because my form is setup with only the 3 fields so thats all the form.save is looking for.

Comment: yes in that case you have to save this field explicitly. something like form.ip= your_ip then form.save()